# Saving PreviewImage has a green tint - Android

Tags: android, image-processing

There's a green tint after saving the image.  The preview image on the surface holder look normal.  What can I do to remove this?

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        try {

            if (saveImg) {
                int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

                YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width, height, null);

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, out);

                byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/newimage.png");
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
                byte[] blobArray = os.toByteArray();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(blobArray);
                fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting this value for the white-balance to remove the green tint:

```
parameters.set("whitebalance", WHITE_BALANCE_FLUORESCENT);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```